# Eclipse not importing bukkit

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, minecraft, bukkit

I'm new to eclipse, java, and practically everything related to this question..

Im trying to code a minecraft Bukkit plugin, real basic, but it doesn't seem to import the bukkit jar properly. Ive used the Bukkit Buildtools and I got both the spigot file and the bukkit from the Target folder. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the error messages in the Problems view (or Markers view, if you prefer it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple Reasons why this may not work:

1. You are using Java 15 JRE. You definitly need JDK 8 for Bukkit and Spigot. If you wanna use Paper, you can use JDK 11
2. You have bukkit and spigot as dependencies (I would recommend to use paper, because its more up-to-date). Just use one of them, and you dont need craftbukkit until you want to edit packages
3. If you extend Java Plugin, you have to use the onEnable, onLoad and onDisable-functions. Then you register your EventListener in onEnable and you should be fine.
   You probably can get the functions by hovering over JavaPlugin.

If you have any questions, feel free to contact me :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you use the tutorial to make a plugin? It doesn't seem like you did, because you need a Maven Install program to make a Spigot plugin. Read this: https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Plugin_Tutorial
2. Your `plugin.yml` shouldn't be in the same folder as the class folder. Read the tutorial I linked above. Also, you need a `pom.xml` file. Just read the tutorial...
3. You don't need CraftBukkit.
4. Did you import every single thing? Importing "Bukkit" doesn't import everything in Bukkit.